# Using Workflow to Copy Calendar Items Between Sites in Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar, sharepoint-workflow

I am having problems figuring out a calendar workflow and am beginning to think what I need cannot be done w/out using .NET. I want to copy calendar items up and down between sites.

The site collection structure is Office-->Division-->Branch.  There are 5 divisions under the office and multiple branches under each division. Each is a separate site with its own own calendar.

I want to populate a calendar on one site and have the item pushed up or down the site chain to another site calendar. So I need to be able to promote calendar events up AND down between calendars on different sites within the same site collection. Also, I don’t need the whole item copied. I need all fields except one because each site has its own set of check box values for one of the fields.

All my research has indicated this can’t be done without programming and I do not have Visual Studio. I have heard BCS may be a solution but am not sure that we have it. We are using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Server but many things are not available to me such as Data Sources.  One recommendation I got was to have one site (office) and put everything below it as site pages.  So divisions and branches would just be pages, not separate sites.  However, this seems like it would get out of hand quickly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like my site structure is not optimal as SharePoint lists and libraries do not easily flow between sites.  I will need to change the structure so all the divisions and branches are site pages, not sites.  This way everything will live in the same site and it will be much easier to move data around via workflow.

In this case, I won't need to move any data between calendars because now I can use one calendar for the office, divisions and branches and create different views to show the required data.